# text field css issue

Tags: html, css

I am using html 5. I have a input field in my form and the following is the code

```
<input name="address" id="address" type="text" onFocus="if(this.value =='Address' ) this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Address'" value="Address">
```

The css for the input field is

```
input#address{ width:411px; border:0px; height:50px; line-height:50px; padding-left:15px;}
```

The problem is width. The text field width differs from Firefox and ie 7. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have their own default styles, if you want your page to look the same accross browsers use a [css reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset) then manually style you elements.

Comment: Reset CSS is not going to solve the problem as here padding is causing problem. which is applied on the element,

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to display properties as like this

```
input#address{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply. But still it didn't get fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try reset the padding and margin of the input element

```
input {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: along with padding need to set border 0 as well but here padding is one of the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest to remove padding or border as that will change the requirement.

The reason is different browsers have different box modal

Some time adding a doctype to the page solves the problem but thats not always the case.

You can use following code to make sure your box appear same in all major browsers.

```
input#address{
  width:411px;
  border:0px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  padding-left:15px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: box sizing doesn't work in IE7 but IE7's default behaviour is similar to Border-box so here we are making all other browsers behaving like IE7